# How to avoid conflicts with other programs using shared memory and semaphore

Tags: c++, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory, conflict

I have program that uses shared memory and protects it with semaphore to communicate with other instances of the same program. I am concerned about security of my shared memory and semaphores.

1. How can I ensure that semaphore and shm that I use won't be opened by other program that will mess it up?  There is one way of running the program under separate user with his own usergroup and protecting shared objects with restricting them to be accessible only by that user and group. Is that the answer to my question, or are there some pitfalls, maybe on windows?
2. Is there some way to protect them if I have to run all programs under same user, or if some programs are run as root (there are always such programs, aren't they)?
3. I started up with setting a default 'key' for shm & semaphore for all the instances that want to communicate together. But there could be different program that has taken the 'key' already. Is there some technique to solve such problem? I was thinking about selecting a range of 'keys' (ie. key would be integer in range 1000 - 2000) where if program is unable to acquire key of default value it tries to get other key from the range.

I found related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128368/detecting-and-controlling-unauthorized-shared-memory-reads), but it does not say anything about my questions 2 and 3. Other than that question I can't find anything related to shm and semaphore conflicts and protection, seems like it is not taken much into account when writing programs.

My situation is that I have a program that wants to communicate with other instances of the same program. There are run multiple 'sets' of instances of the same program, where programs of one 'set' communicate together, and programs in other 'set' communicate together. They communicate through semaphore protected shared memory. Program is run on various *nix platforms and on windows too. They should be up and running 24/7 for few years and should be reliable and safe, that's the reason I'm concerned about the conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semaphores "protect" the shared memory only if all the programs using it are collaborating. I.e. it allows the program which wants to play nicely not to corrupt the shared objects.

This however doesn't guarantee that a malicious program will be able to jump in and corrupt the shared structures if it wants to. I don't know of any security-related features in C++ standard, therefore I would suggest to resort to OS-specific means.

This means that you might need to have different code on Linux, Windows, Mac etc. (whichever are your target platforms), maybe even different code on different OS versions.

Comment: Yes, I alraedy have os-specific parts of code for different platforms as it is required because of different function calls for using shared mem and semaphores.

Question is - what are the tricks to protect the memory/semaphore from being accidentaly accessed by other programs?

Comment: On Windows, you should look at [SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379560%28VS.85%29.aspx). This structure is used in [CreateSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx) (used for [shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28VS.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is about conflicts, how about using a GUID as a name? Nobody (within our life times) will ever come up with this `{897917A3-D44E-4f0d-A458-1318152CCCDA}` by chance.

As for protection against malicious software, I'd utilize the security mechanisms in the operating system. Require services to run within the scope of some user, and then restrict access to external objects such as semaphores and shared memory to that user only. As long as the security of that user isn't breached, then your system should be safe.

On Windows you'd typically use the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structures when you create the semaphore and file mapping, and mode_t (with `creat`/`open`/`chmod`/etc) on Unix.

Don't apply the method of *security by obscurity*, by making the names "hard to guess" and believe they are secret. It will only help to not interfer with other applications on the same system. It will not stop malicious users/code, since the names of the object may not be a secret.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't use GUID strings as on *nix I'm forced to use shmget() and semget() because of some limitations, and they accept key_t (which is int) as parameter.

Comment: Ah... I forgot about the semaphores in Unix. I haven't worked with Unix since 2000 or so. Why don't you let one process randomly choose a free semaphore key, and store it in the shared memory. Then the other processes can acquire the semaphore handles through the shared memory. Of course, you'd have to employ some locking mechanism that protects the other processes from race conditions when reading the semaphore keys.